# Kubernetes autoscaled pod access

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an app called app1 which exposes a Nodeport service on port 5000, this app can be autoscaled by keda so there can be many replicas of it.

Now I have another app called app2 which needs to access all the dynamic pods of app1 via hostname, currently this does not work.

How can I fix this, what type of service needs to be exposed by app1 for this?
Thanks

Not sure, I would have thought Nodeport should have worked

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correct, you want to access each pod of the service directly instead of only one through the service load balancer.

To achieve this, you can use a headless service (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services), i.e. specifying `None` for the `ClusterIP`.

The DNS reslover then will return a list of all pod IPs instead of only one service IP.

This is useful e.g. if you have to clear caches of all individual pods.

You don't need a Nodeport for that and it can be used side-by-side with another service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with clusterIp=None how can I access the replica podes? 
Basically, when the pods comes up dynamically I want to access them via hostname, beforehand app2 would not know about all the ip’s app1 pods will be associated with

Comment: As written, a DNS lookup for the service name will provide you with all IP addresses of all pods. If you requirement is to have a stable name for each pod, then you should use a sateful set with stable network ids - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use DAPR to connect services basically I think you should try [service invocation](https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/service-invocation/service-invocation-overview/) , it will require to modify the code of app2 a little but it will help you a lot and free your tied app.